# Could Not Install Nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm a total newbei on all this DNS stuff. I installed the BIND9 ISPConfig and nginx I defined some nameservers for my account via my domain provider's panel (Natro) which is ns1.ostimdenevar.com and  my ip is 37.148.208.22. 
My problem is:
**I cannot reach my domain but my ip works.** I checked my config with http://www.intodns.com/ostimdenevar.com

It says: ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond:
The ones that did not respond are:
37.148.208.22 37.148.208.32

I tried to configure that via ISPConfig. But error didnt change. I tried to configure bind manually but no change.

I dont a way to fix this problem or even dont know where to look. Where should I start?

This is the bind config files that I use now:

File: named.conf.local

```
    zone "ostimdenevar.com" {
         type master;
         file "/etc/bind/db.ostimdenevar.com";
    };
```

File: db.ostimdenevar.com

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.ostimdenevar.com. root.ostimdenevar.com. (
                          1         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns.1.ostimdenevar.com.
ns      IN      A       37.148.208.22
```

File: named.conf.options

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
    // the all-0's placeholder.

     forwarders {
            89.19.21.250;
     };

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First look at this, your NS record has an extra . (dot)

ns.1.ostimdenevar.com should be ns1.ostimdenevar.com

your A record, should be "ns1" and not "ns" to match up with the NS record.

in short:

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.ostimdenevar.com. root.ostimdenevar.com. (
                          1         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.ostimdenevar.com.
@       IN      NS      ns2.ostimdenevar.com.
ns1     IN      A       37.148.208.22
ns2     IN      A       37.148.208.32
```

Besides the errors in the zone file, you have an ip there: 37.148.208.32 which I do no see in your zone file, so add that as ns2.ostimdenevar.com.

Also if this is @home or @work, using NAT. Do not forget to forward port 53 to whatever server that is taking care off your dns.

Comment: OK. I changed the db.ostimdenevar.com by your records. And it seams that http://www.intodns.com/ error disapears. How can I add ns2?

Comment: Updated above zone file, you can load this on both your servers and it should work.

Comment: should i change anothger think because http://www.intodns.com/ostimdenevar.com still complains about .32 ip